# Windows 7 reboots after bios logo with no message

Tags: windows-7, boot

PC manufactured somewere in 2008, with an Asus motherboard and BIOS. Yesterday I put it in sleep mode, and then unplugged the power cable. After few hours I tried to boot my PC and now my computer always restarts with no message if i try to boot fom my hard disk.

Restart takes about 13 seconds, I hear single "beep" sound.

I had this problem before. I had to remove BIOS battery to reset BIOS and that helped. But this time resetting the BIOS memory does not help. I have tried changing many BIOS options, including SATA mode to IDE/AHCI/RAID.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
    1. Insert Windows7 installation media and run the installer
    2. Wait while installer UI loads
    3. Reset (unplug power cable)
    4. Boot from hard disk ans it will allow you to choose SAFE MODE
    5. In safe mode, just restart PC.

I don't know the reason of this problem but i fixed it only this way, after 2 hours of reboots, bios tweaks, etc...